Unable to get sorted Projects in NextJS/MongoDB project
I get the following status codes in the terminal with my code but do not understand why. Here is the code. I believe it may be an issue with the folder structure but I am not sure. I have debugged and see no issues with any values be undefined, and see no such errors in terminal. I get these status codes also:
GET /api/Project?userId=6656e135c761e2d4bace9ef7&sortKey=createdAt&sortOrder=desc 500 in 59ms
GET /api/Project/User/6656e135c761e2d4bace9ef7 404 in 127ms

ProjectList.jsx:
useEffect(() => {
    const selectedColumn = Object.keys(sortMap).find((key) => sortMap[key]);

    const selectedOrder = Object.values(sortMap).find((val) => null !== val);

    try {
      const sortedProjects = getSortedProjects(
        currentUser.id,
        selectedColumn,
        selectedOrder
      );
      setProjects(sortedProjects);
      setRefreshingProject(true);
    } catch (error) {
      throw new Error("Failed to sort Projects", error);
    }
  }, [sortMap]);

api.js:
export async function getSortedProjects(userId, column, order) {
  try {
    const response = await axios.get(
      `/api/Project?userId=${userId}&sortKey=${column}&sortOrder=${order}`
    );

    return response.data.projects;
  } catch (error) {
    throw new Error("Failed to get Projects by User id");
  }
}

/app/api/Project/route.js:
export async function GET(req) {
  const url = new URL(req.url);

  const searchParams = new URLSearchParams(url.search);

  const userId = searchParams.get("userId");
  const sortKey = searchParams.get("sortKey");
  const sortOrder = searchParams.get("sortOrder");

  try {
    let sortObj = {};
    if (sortOrder === "desc") {
      sortObj[sortKey] = -1;
    } else {
      sortObj[sortKey] = 1;
    }

    const projects = await Project.find({ userId: userId }).sort(sortObj);

    return new NextResponse.json({ projects });
  } catch (error) {
    return NextResponse.json({ message: "Error", error }, { status: 500 });
  }
}

I have tried putting the endpoint in Project > User > [id] and refactoring so that id comes from params and not searchParams of a new URL.
Have console.log a lot and see no reason why I shouldn't get the results other than the route endpoint, which I cannot see why doesn't work.

Can you share what's the error in the catch in the GET function?

I believe it fails here: const response = await axios.get(
/api/Project?userId=${userId}&sortKey=${column}&sortOrder=${order}
);, the error is blank: {
message: "Error",
error: { }
}

Yes, but if it sends the parameters correctly then the issue must be related to the server side. Anyway, have you been able to fix the problem?

I couldn't help so much, sorry but happy to hear that it's fixed. Good luck!
